# failed to call Adapter method from fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

I am using fragments with tabs.
I have two fragments:
`AddTask.java` and `AddedTask.java`

I have one Adaper class
Adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<Reminder_Database> lists;
TextView title, date,time,note,date_edit,time_edit;
EditText title_edit,note_edit;
AddedTask addedTask;
int ids;
public Adapter(Context context, List<Reminder_Database> list, AddedTask addedTask) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.lists=list;
    this.addedTask=addedTask;
}
```

above mentioned code is of adapter. Now i want number of list items in my first fragment `AddTask.java` but it returns `null`.

I have tried like

```
Adapter adapter=new Adapter(context,lists,addedTask);
adapter.getcount();
```

but it returns `null`.

Maybe Context of fragment `AddedTask` is returning `null`.

Please don't get confused between `AddTask` and `AddedTask`.

I want `getCount()` of adapter to be called in `AddTask` or else i want value from `AddedTask` on opening activity.

Comment: where is context initialized and what does `this` refer to in your code?

Comment: sorry, actually replaced context with getActivity() and insead of this it is list object. but actualy simply i am unable to call adapetr method to my first fragment AddTask.

Comment: how is your list populated in the first place

Comment: I edited my answer once check.

Comment: @Viren look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html and https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus which is a third party library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be something like

```
Adapter adapter=new Adapter(getActivity(),list,addedTask);
adapter.getcount();
```

where `list` is an object of type `List<Reminder_Database>`.

To get value from `AddedTask` to `AddTask`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public int count;

}
```

First set the value in `AddedTask`

```
public class AddedTask extends Fragment{

    ....
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).count = adapter.getcount();
```

}

To get it in the other `Fragment`:

```
public class AddedTask extends Fragment{

    ....
    int count = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).count;

}
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: @Zygotelnit Actually list is the object of type List<Reminder_databse>. The confusion lies at addedTask because that is also fragment and i have called that simply as  AddedTask addedtask; and passed that to adapter. is that okay???

Comment: @Zygotelnit One more thing is there that is i am  getting li st count in AddedTask storing it in one variable and passing that to AddTask is possible? and yes this should be done on start of Application too.

Comment: @Viren: can you explain your new question a little more clearly ?

Comment: @Viren: please see edited answer ... I think that's what you meant :)

Comment: simply donee.... but yet one confusion is there that why i am unable to acess that getcount(). any ways Thank you..

Comment: `adapter.getcount()` should be possible ... what is the error you are seeing ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your parameters are mismatching

this -> List will not work,
And fragment context should be taken from activity.

```
 getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

Use some list object:-

```
Adapter adapter=new Adapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),list,addedTask);
```

Comment: please see my comment to first reply